# Iterate over array in Ember Handlebars each

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an object that I'm already iterating over to display the content in a template using handlebars {{#each}} - however, within each object there is an array that I also need to loop over.

Need to achieve something like.

```
{{#each item}}

  {{title}}
  {{rating}}

  {{#each array_field}}
    {{field}}
    {{anotherField}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a pointer var to the current item, then query your array property:

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  {{item.title}}
  {{item.rating}}

  {{#each otherItem in item.arrayField}}
    {{otherItem.field}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```